# primefaces command button label change after click

Tags: button, primefaces, label, commandbutton

I have a commandbutton that inserts data into database. I want to change button label after I click it and then it will be disabled.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with a boolean value in your baking bean

in your bean

```
boolean buttonDisabled = false;
```

.xhtml

```
<p:commandButton "#{yourBean.buttonDisabled ? 'old label' : 'new label'}" disabled="#{yourBean.buttonDisabled}">
     <f:setPropertyActionListener value="true"
         target="#{yourBean.buttonDisabled}" />
</p:commandButton>
```